# Optimize query by looking at query plan

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

optimize Sqlserver 2005 query by query plan

I have a following query which takes 1.7 seconds to pull 72 records can take more time if more items available.

When i run query plan i found expensive operation is "ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag = 0 AND ActivationDateTime" b/c non of them having index

```
ReviewCompleteFlag value can be 0 or 1
ReviewItemDeleteFlag values can be 0 or 1
itemid is foreign key
```

is there a way i can optimize this query ?

```
SELECT

      TOP 200000

    ItemId
    FROM
    ItemReview (nolock)
    WHERE ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag = 0 AND ActivationDateTime is null
    ORDER BY ReviewPriority DESC
```

Comment: Create indexes on columns you frequently have in your WHERE clause. Microsoft has a white paper on the issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix on ItemReview (ReviewCompleteFlag,ReviewItemDeleteFlag,ActivationDateTime,ReviewPriority) INCLUDE (ItemId)` would be an optimum index for that query. Whether or not it is optimum for your overall workload impossible for us to tell you.

Comment: @Martin would it be useful to have `bit` columns as the leading columns?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - For this single query we have been told about it with the three and-ed equality conditions it would make no odds. Having `ActivationDateTime` leading might benefit other queries.

Comment: Why are you using `TOP` and why are you using `NOLOCK`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I would probably default to listing non-BIT columns first, and maybe even only including the BIT columns. Due to cardinality they're not likely to help the WHERE clause whether they're in the key or not. This is just speculation based on a small amount of testing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - But to do an index seek and have the results ordered by `ReviewPriority` to avoid a sort the three columns with the `=` need to be the first three in the key with `ReviewPriority` as the fourth. I did only say "an" optimum index. What is actually optimum depends on the other queries.

Comment: Although I suppose `ActivationDateTime,ReviewPriority` would avoid a sort too but would need the residual predicate evaluated against all matching rows. Which would be 4 times as many assuming 50% split for both bit columns.

Comment: @Faisal is `ItemId` the primary key? Is it clustered?

Comment: (My point being, if ItemId is the clustering key, it doesn't be included and won't change the plan or the reads.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Bertrand itemid is foreign key

Comment: @swasheck using top to filter out if there is huge data, nolock because don't want to keep readlock on table !!!

Comment: @Faisalkhan so you're okay with skipping rows or reading rows twice? Maybe you should consider read committed snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As booleans (even if defined as int, you state they only have two values) I would suspect that neither ReviewCompleteFlag or ReviewItemDeleteFlag would be helped by indexes. Indexes generally require more variablity in the data to be useful.

I would consider trying indexes on ActivationDateTime and ReviewPriority.

It is also possible that once you have the index on  ActivationDateTime that a derived table might be faster (At least then you are applying the unindexed booleans to a smaller set and that could work to your advantage (try first of course and measure with your datbase setup and adatabase):

```
SELECT
  TOP 200000
ItemId
FROM
    (SELECT ItemID, ReviewCompleteFlag, ReviewItemDeleteFlag, ReviewPriority 
    FROM  ItemReview 
    WHERE ActivationDateTime is null) IR  WITH (nolock)
WHERE ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag = 0     ORDER BY ReviewPriority DESC
```

Comment: You need to either add `WITH` before `(nolock)` or move the hint inside the derived table. Currently SQL Server thinks that's a column definition. Also the derived table does not expose `ActivationDateTime`, so it should not be mentioned in the outer `WHERE`.

Comment: tried SELECT
  TOP 200000
ItemId
FROM
    (SELECT ItemID, ReviewCompleteFlag, ReviewItemDeleteFlag, ReviewPriority 
    FROM  ItemReview  (nolock)
    WHERE ActivationDateTime is null) 
WHERE ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag = 0 AND ActivationDateTime is null
ORDER BY ReviewPriority DESC

Comment: ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Error Code:
156

Query = SELECT
  TOP 200000
ItemId
FROM
    (SELECT ItemID,
ReviewCompleteFlag, ReviewItemDeleteFlag, ReviewPriority

    FROM  ItemReview  (nolock)
    WHERE ActivationDateTime
is null) 
WHERE ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag
= 0 AND ActivationDateTime is null
ORDER BY ReviewPriority
DESC

Comment: No problem. FWIW this performs exactly the same as the original query with Martin's index suggestion (with or without the INCLUDE column). Which performs better than any alternative I had (in SQL Server 2012, it seems having the BIT columns in the key is marginally helpful). Need to do more testing, and of course we only know about this one query, but re-writing it doesn't seem to help. Again, FWIW.

Comment: @Faisal (1) please don't paste a bunch of code in a comment, it's not readable at all (2) when copying code, please make sure to copy it all before complaining that it doesn't work. You missed an alias `IR` on the derived table.

Comment: this worked

SELECT
  TOP 200000
ItemId
FROM
    (SELECT ItemID, ReviewCompleteFlag, ReviewItemDeleteFlag, ReviewPriority 
    FROM  ItemReview WITH (nolock)
    WHERE ActivationDateTime is null) IR  
WHERE ReviewCompleteFlag =0 AND ReviewItemDeleteFlag = 0     ORDER BY ReviewPriority DESC

Comment: looks good to me following is io plan
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.027195098
0.003125

Comment: before it was 
0.0
0.0
0.0056306305
88.345345

Comment: i am happy to be stackoverflow you are guys are valueable to be with specially thanks to @HLGEM